# Image link box off in Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, hyperlink

I'm having a hard time researching this problem since I don't know exactly what the box around the image link is called.

I have this simple, basic code in a text widget on a WordPress site:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/ShiversShavedIce"><img src="http://shiversshavedice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/facebook.png" title="Shivers Shaved Ice on Facebook" /></a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/shiverstexas"><img src="http://shiversshavedice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/twitter.png" title="Shivers Shaved Ice on Twitter" /></a>
<a href="http://instagram.com/shiverstexas"><img src="http://shiversshavedice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/instagram.png" title="Shivers Shaved Ice on Instagram" /></a>
<a href="http://visitor.r20.constantcontact.com/d.jsp?llr=sn7abbnab&p=oi&m=1113504903602&sit=8kb6nh8hb&f=37e341e0-2a18-443e-9467-cedf64a6e113"><img src="http://shiversshavedice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/newsletter.png" title="Keep Up With Us!" /></a>
<a href="mailto:shiverstexas@gmail.com"><img src="http://shiversshavedice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/email.png" title="Email Shivers" /></a>
```

In Firefox it works fine.  When you click one of the links, a sort of marching-ants type box appears around the images, only the ants aren't marching.

[image]

But in Chrome, that link box thingy shows up underneath the image link:

[image]

I'm on a mac, the first screen cap is mine, the second is the client's on a PC.  It seems like this would be a float issue of some kind?  But this is a very basic WordPress theme that has not been customized all that much.  I think the links still work fine in the Chrome situation, but the box showing up underneath doesn't look great and is a bit distracting.

Thanks, I know this is probably super basic, I'm just a bit lost.

Comment: The box around is called outline ... it's a property triggered by the focus state on the link. The issue can be a problem with another CSS.

Comment: Please also include the CSS that you have for the relevant HTML. It looks here like you just need to set `a { display: inline-block }` in your CSS. Check out the link above by showdev for a more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single pixel wide grey outline is the default `:focus` styles in the browser. You can fix the layout of the outline using `display: inline-block;` on the `a` tags. This will make their layout expand to wrap the `img` elements.

While not the most-precise CSS selector, you could do something like this.

```
.widget-area .textwidget a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Additionally, you can customize the outline styles using CSS like this.

```
.widget-area .textwidget a:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
    /*Some other styles here.*/
}
```

Comment: Yep +1 beat me .... Another selector can be `.textwidget > a`

Comment: Thanks so much, I'd upvote your answer, Alexander, but don't have the clout here yet.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Thanks!  The inline-block solution worked perfectly.